# Simple Python concatenation question

Tags: python

If I type the following into IDLE, it gives me the result of 'wordwordword':

```
print("word" * 3)
```

If I go through the following steps in IDLE, it gives me the same result:

```
sentence = input() #I type "word"
number = int(input()) #I type it to int because input() saves as a string, I type "3"
print(sentence * number)
```

But then, if I try to use the exact same three lines above in a Notepad document to create it as a script, I only get the result of 'word' instead of 'wordwordword'

Any thoughts?

Comment: Without the *actual* output and the Python version number, we'll have a hard time guessing.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. It prints "wordwordword" in my pc when run as script. Maybe you overlooked something in your saved script? (I'm running Python 2.7, since you're using print function and `input`, I assume you're using Python 3.x)

Comment: Works for me too. Version info would be useful.

Comment: I am using the 3.x Python version.  I figured that since I am new to the language, I should try to learn the newest version - is that faulty logic?

Comment: Yes, you should learn on 2.7. Most of the tutorials and libraries are written for 2.7

Comment: since `input([prompt])` is Equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))` you should write `3` instead of `"3"`

Comment: No, you should not learn on 2.7.  Find a 3.2 tutorial and start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code works well in python **3**.

With python **2**, just replace input by raw_input() like that :

```
sentence = raw_input()
number = int(raw_input())
print(sentence * number)
```

You can read the [PEP 3111](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/) to understand the difference and the motivation between input and raw_input in python2 and python3.

Comment: @Rob: Did you accept this answer even though your code doesn't work?

Comment: There is no problem with my code, it works well with python2 ;-) The code of @Rob works well in python3.

Comment: @Sandro Munda: Rob's comment seems to indicate it is not working.

Comment: @S.Lott Try it. It's not a problem due to my code. I think my answer was accepted because Rob has realized.If there is a problem, I'm listening.

Comment: @Sandro Munda: I'm still not commenting on your code or your explanation.  I'm still asking about Rob's comment, which seems to indicate it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try `raw_input()`:

```
sentence = raw_input()
number = int(raw_input())
print(sentence * number)
```

The [documentation says](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) that:

> **`input([prompt])`**
>
> Equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`.

`eval()` executes Python code, which isn't what you want.

Comment: This throws a syntax error. I am using the newest version of Python, could that be a problem?  Even when I just use a simple 'raw_input()' I get an error.

Comment: Ohhhh, never mind. Python3 renamed `raw_input()` to `input()`, which now makes sense. Carry on ;)